# Line break in \makecell in tabular cell in AASTeX results in extra column width?

Tags: tables, spacing, makecell, aastex

I would like to use `\makecell` with to add line breaks in my table. However, this results in extra column width, with the width being what it would have been had the text not been broken onto two lines. As far as I can tell, this only seems to be a problem with the AASTeX document class. It does not occur with the basic `article`.

Are there any suggestions for allowing `\makecell` to provide proper column width in AASTeX documents?

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{aastex63}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
header0 & \makecell{header1\\text after linebreak} & header2 \\
\midrule
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround.

```
\documentclass{aastex63}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
header0 & $\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}header1\\ text after linebreak\end{tabular}$ & header2 \\
\midrule
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: oh `$` ?? +1 I did try tabular late last night but  that failed and it was too late to trace what aastex is doing here.

Comment: @David Carliste: I have no explanation but it seems to work...

Comment: I can probably make due with this. Upvoted, but I'll leave the question open for a bit longer in case a solution for `\makecell` comes up (for my real use case, it makes things a bit simpler). If you happen to stumble across details of what's going wrong, or why this solution (with `$`) works, that'd also be good to see. Thank you much!

Comment: aastex has its own extended table formatting called "deluxetable" that *should* provide multiline heading cells without `\makecell`. The documentation is sketchy so I don't know for sure.